# View and Set Operators MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an academic project that asks to use set operators (or join / subquery). The task is: **Display customer id and name for all customers who have at least one order in April and at least one order in May but no orders in June.**

```
CREATE VIEW oeOrdersPriorYear AS
SELECT cust_customers.customer_id, cust_customers.customer_name_last, cust_customers.customer_name_first, extract( month from oe_orderHeaders.order_date) as order_month
FROM cust_customers
JOIN oe_orderHeaders
ON cust_customers.customer_id = oe_orderHeaders.customer_id
ORDER BY order_month;
```

My attempt at the code is:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
FROM oeOrdersPriorYear
WHERE order_month = '5'

MINUS
SELECT customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
FROM oeOrdersPriorYear
WHERE order_month = '6';
```

Is this valid? I run in MySQL so I am not sure if the syntax is correct. What is another way to write this with a subquery / join?

[chart reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Ocb.png)

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ? There is no `MINUS` operator in MySQL.

Comment: I am using MySQL. The task asks to use set operators but they maybe supplemented by subquery / join on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use conditional aggregation based filtering in `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
FROM oeOrdersPriorYear 
WHERE order_month IN ('4','5','6')   -- consider only from April, May and June
GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last 
HAVING SUM(order_month = '4') AND   -- atleast one in April
       SUM(order_month = '5') AND   -- atleast one in May 
       NOT SUM(order_month = '6')   -- no order in June
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not recognise `MINUS` and `INTERSECT`. You can use NOT IN or NOT EXISTS which works as MINUS in MySQL.

```
select customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
from oeOrdersPriorYear
where order_month IN ('4','5') and
customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
NOT IN (select customer_id, customer_name_first, customer_name_last
from oeOrdersPriorYear
where order_month = '6');
```